Unable to access comments from jira worklogs via python-jira
I am trying to retreive worklog entries from Jira Service Management Cloud in python by using the jira-python library.
Everything works fine, except getting the comment from each worklog. The documentation is quite vague on this.
My code currently looks like this:
jira = JIRA(server, basic_auth=(email,token))

# define date filter
startDate = datetime.date(2024, 2, 1)
endDate = datetime.date(2024, 2, 27)

#define jql to filter issues
jql = "project in (XY) AND issuetype in ('[System] Incident', '[System] Service request') AND status = Closed AND resolutiondate >= {} AND resolutiondate <= {}".format(startDate, endDate)

#incremental fetch of issues and storage into issues_all
pos = 0;
batch = 100;
issues_all = []
while True:
    issues_batch = jira.search_issues(jql_str=jql, startAt=pos, maxResults=batch, fields=['worklog','customfield_10202','customfield_10198','customfield_10191'])
    if issues_batch == []:
        break
    else:
        issues_all += issues_batch
    pos += batch

with open('jiraExport.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=";")
    fields = ["Issue", "Issue ID","Warranty Basis","Warranty","Warranty Reason","Worklog ID", "Author Name", "Author Email","Date", "Time Spent", "Description"]

    writer.writerow(fields)

    for issue in issues_all:
        current_issue = jira.issue(issue)
        worklogs = current_issue.fields.worklog.worklogs
        for worklog in worklogs:
            worklog_fields = []
            worklog_fields.append(current_issue.key)
            worklog_fields.append(worklog.issueId)
            worklog_fields.append(current_issue.fields.customfield_10202)
            worklog_fields.append(current_issue.fields.customfield_10198)
            worklog_fields.append(current_issue.fields.customfield_10191)
            worklog_fields.append(worklog.id)
            worklog_fields.append(worklog.author.displayName)
            worklog_fields.append(worklog.author.emailAddress)
            worklog_fields.append(functions.datetime_to_date(worklog.started))
            worklog_fields.append(functions.seconds_to_industryHours(worklog.timeSpentSeconds))
            worklog_fields.append(worklog.comment) <-----
            writer.writerow(worklog_fields)

I found some stuff which referenced worklog.comment should work, but I always get the following error, when running my code:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\jira\resources.py", line 193, in __getattr__
    return self[item]  # type: ignore
           ~~~~^^^^^^
TypeError: 'Worklog' object is not subscriptable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Development\Projects\Jira Interface\main.py", line 58, in <module>
    worklog_fields.append(worklog.comment)
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\xy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\jira\resources.py", line 198, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(
AttributeError: <class 'jira.resources.Worklog'> object has no attribute 'comment' ('Worklog' object is not subscriptable)

Any ideas how to get the comment of each worklog?

Figured out the problem:
The code is working, but I had a worklog in my project that had no comment. Therefore the worklog object had no "Comment" attribute.
By checking if the object has the attribute, my code is now running fine:
if hasattr(worklog, 'comment') and worklog.raw['comment']:
     print("Worklog comment: ", worklog.raw['comment'])
else:
     print("Worklog has an empty comment or no comment attribute.")

